# Android why is activity visible after onStop called

Tags: android

I have placed prints in all my activity call backs and what I am seeing is a sequence 
onStart()->onResume()->onStop()  but after onStop is called I see the same activity the main activity displaying.  Docs indicate this is called when activity is no longer visible but it looks to me like its getting called when my service is put in the foreground.  So which one is guaranteed to be called when it becomes not visible?  onStop() was called but my activity is still visible and user can interact with it.

Comment: Looks like maybe onPause() is the one that is guaranteed to get called when its not visible.  onStop() is not necessarily related to the visibility of the activity.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Diagram would suggest that activity is no longer visible then onStop() gets called right?

Comment: That's correct.  I have tested it by implementing each method and putting toast messages in them.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question of why onStop() is called when the activity is still visible (and in my case, onPause() was never called).